# Mantissa size of double variable compile with GCC in Intel® Atom™

Tags: c++, gcc, x86-64, mantissa

I'am runing a C++ software with double variables. My platform is upboard with an Intel® Atom™ x5-z8350 (1.92 GHz). The OS is Ubuntu server 18.04 and I compile the software with GCC 7.5.0.
I compile my .cpp only with the optimization flag -o2.

How can I find / what is the size of the mantissa for the double variable floating point representation? Is is the standard 64-bit format with 53 bits mantissa or the x86/x86-64 80-bit format with 64 bits mantissa?

Thank you very much.
Gabriel

Comment: Generally speaking, all x86-64 platforms use standard IEEE 754 definition. It's extremely rare to find a non-conforming chip.

Comment: Check [`std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits).

Comment: The problem is that the FPU internally has more bits but every time a double is saved to memory you loose those. So the numeric limits might not be totally accurate unless you set a compiler option to enforce IEEE conformance.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow With x64, floating-point calculations are typically performed by SIMD units, not by FPU (x87). Some implementations use FPU for `long double` calculations. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6GTePPdEc.

Comment: On non-Windows, GCC uses 80-bit `long double`.  If you really want that extra precision at the cost of speed, use that type.

Comment: @DanielLangr Then setting the ieee compliance flag won't hurt performance. I know at least gcc used to have the problem of playing loose with using the 80-bit format in the fpu.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: I think you're talking about `-ffloat-store` to force rounding of temporaries to the actual C type.  You're right, that has no effect on x86-64 builds because `-mfpmath=sse` is the default.  `-fno-fast-math` is also the default.